# How to build an image from an xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml file which stores a previously saved image. The xml file format is the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<image type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>315</rows>
  <cols>387</cols>
  <dt>"3u"</dt>
  <data>
    253 236 233 253 236 233 253 236 233 254 237 234 254 237 234 255 238
    235 255 238 235 255 238 235 253 236 233 253 236 233 253 236 233 254
    237 234 254 237 234 255 238 235 255 238 235 255 238 235 253 238 236
    253 238 236 253 238 236 254 239 237 254 239 ...253 232 230
</data>
</image>
</opencv_storage>
```

I'd like to know if there is a way of re-building that image from php.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an internal format used by the opencv package. Did you consult their documentation for this?

Comment: Yes, you are right this image comes from opencv. However, the documentation only provides information for reading this using opencv. Since there is not opencv for php, I the documentation cannot help.

Comment: At least you should be able to find out what type of image this might be. Without such information it is impossible to make anything from those numbers. apart from that you can always use opencvs cli utilitys and control them from within php.